# How to update error messages object with Reactive forms in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

this is my code

```
public errorMessages;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.startErrorMessage();    
}

private startErrorMessage() {
  this.errorMessages = maxLength: this.translate.instant('util.maxLength', {
        maxL: this.form?.controls?.firstName?.errors ? 10 : 20
      })
}
```

Then in html:

```
<p *ngIf="form?.controls?.firstName?.errors">
  {{ form?.controls?.firstName?.errors | showErrorMessage: errorMessages }}
/p>
```

The problem here is that `this.errorMessages` is checked only once, meaning it will always return `20` for the ternary check in `maxL` field, since the first value is always `null`.

I have tried listening to changes, like this:

```
private listenToChanges() {
  this.form.controls.firstName.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.startErrorMessage();
  }
}
```

and placing `listenToChanges()` in `ngOnInit()` but this introduces some other bugs, while it does fix some of them. Also, it doesn't feel right.

What is the good approach here? How can I make `this.errorMessages` update? What is the good practice here?

EDIT:

```
private startForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [
        { value: '', disabled: true },
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(10),
        ],
})
```

Comment: In reactive forms you can add custom validators when initializing your FormControl. Here is the official documentation for it: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Comment: Please type answer, I have tried this as well...

Comment: Also, I did add validators, this is the message I need to handle.

Comment: Can you share your form group creation and validator?

Comment: Made a small example for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jgbtwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts If you need the translator in your validator you can provide it in the function

Comment: @DevangPatel, edited, see above.

Comment: try that listenToChanges() to ngOnChange() life cycle hook.

Comment: @MaTharBeevi, I don't want to listen only to one property changes.. I need better solution for this.

Comment: @westefan, please adjust this to my question and post answer.. if it works I will mark it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

For custom validator you should mention like below:

```
private startForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [
        { value: '', disabled: true },
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(10),
          customfunction() // your validation logic mention here. write a function/directive call it here
],
})
```